# getItems() method for table returns up to 20 rows

Tags: sapui5

I have a report table that is populated in three different ways, depending on selection filters. At the end of the called report I use the "updateFinished" event to loop through the table entries, paint them zebra style and paint last summary line pink.

SAPUI5 Application version is 1.44.12

```
                        this.oStsTable = this.getView().byId("statusReportTable");

                        this.oStsTable.attachEventOnce("updateFinished", function(oEv) {
                            var aItems = oEv.getSource().getItems();
                            if (aItems && aItems.length > 0) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
                                    if (i === aItems.length - 1) {
                                        aItems[i].addStyleClass("pinkBackground");
                                    } else { 
                                        var even = i % 2;
                                        if (even !== 0 && i < aItems.length) {
                                            aItems[i].addStyleClass("cyanBackground");  
                                        }                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });                         

                        this.byId("statusReportTable").getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState);
```

With the data available, I get back 3 datasets. 7 for case 1, 7 for case 2 and 23 for case 3. With the first two cases everything is OK. Problem is with case 3 (23 records). Debugging on the back-end, I see 23. When table appears, I see again 23. But the getItems() method within "updateFinished" event sees only 20 (!). As result of it (yes, guessed right), line 20 goes pink and the remaining lines without color as loop exits.

Rings any bells?

[image: Correct Data]
[image: Incorrect Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to add a zebra style with a different color in the last row, I recommend doing that only with CSS in your app like below.

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}

table tr:last-of-type {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Found a faster way for the occasion ( setGrowingThreshold(iGrowingThreshold) ) but certainly worth of taking a look and getting rid of the code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to alternate the row colors on your [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table) then I would recommend you to set the property `alternateRowColors` to **true**.

```
<Table id="idProductsTable"
    alternateRowColors="true"
    items="{ path: '/ProductCollection' }">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="Products"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Product" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Supplier" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}"/>
                <Text text="{SupplierName}" /> 
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**Note:** This property can only be used with the Belize and Belize Deep themes. Alternate row coloring is not available for the High Contrast Black/White themes.

Find the properties for sap.m.Table [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table/controlProperties).

Comment: Unfortunately can't do that, I have a theme selector that uses 4 different themes, good to know however, thank you

Comment: That's okay. Instead of using the `attachEventOnce` method to get the items, have you tried using [`attachUpdateFinished`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/attachUpdateFinished) on the `onAfterRendering` method?